# SystemTray open menu right click

Tags: java, system-tray, popupmenu

I just recently start using java. Following some tutorial but can not figure out how to get this thing to work. I trying to get the popupmenu on system tray to open when we do right click on it.(BTW, I'm using OSX). Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
    try {
//                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //adding TrayIcon.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Check the SystemTray support
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    // Create a popup menu components
    MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set auto size");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set tooltip");
    Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Display");
    MenuItem errorItem = new MenuItem("Error");
    MenuItem warningItem = new MenuItem("Warning");
    MenuItem infoItem = new MenuItem("Info");
    MenuItem noneItem = new MenuItem("None");
    MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

    //Add components to popup menu
    popup.add(aboutItem);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(cb1);
    popup.add(cb2);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(displayMenu);
    displayMenu.add(errorItem);
    displayMenu.add(warningItem);
    displayMenu.add(infoItem);
    displayMenu.add(noneItem);
    popup.add(exitItem);

    final TrayIcon trayIcon =
            new TrayIcon(createImage("images.jpeg", "tray icon"),"tooltip",popup);
//        trayIcon.setPopupMenu();

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
        return;
    }

    trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//                popup.show( e.getComponent(), 0,0);
//                popup.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    aboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "This dialog box is run from the About menu item");
        }
    });

    cb1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            int cb1Id = e.getStateChange();
            if (cb1Id == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
            } else {
                trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(false);
            }
        }
    });

    cb2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            int cb2Id = e.getStateChange();
            if (cb2Id == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                trayIcon.setToolTip("Sun TrayIcon");
            } else {
                trayIcon.setToolTip(null);
            }
        }
    });

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MenuItem item = (MenuItem)e.getSource();
            //TrayIcon.MessageType type = null;
            System.out.println(item.getLabel());
            if ("Error".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR;
                trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                        "This is an error message", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR);

            } else if ("Warning".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING;
                trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                        "This is a warning message", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);

            } else if ("Info".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO;
                trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                        "This is an info message", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);

            } else if ("None".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE;
                trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                        "This is an ordinary message", TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE);
            }
        }
    };

    errorItem.addActionListener(listener);
    warningItem.addActionListener(listener);
    infoItem.addActionListener(listener);
    noneItem.addActionListener(listener);

    exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tray.remove(trayIcon);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

//Obtain the image URL
protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
    URL imageURL = ListFrame.class.getResource(path);

    if (imageURL == null) {
        System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
        return null;
    } else {
        return (new ImageIcon(imageURL, description)).getImage();
    }
}
}
```